# How to get option value using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the options values off this website, the html looks like this

```
<select id="raff_size" name="size" class="required-entry">
                                    <option value="">Storlek</option>
                                                    <option value="e8f7f9e31e2adb7ca18db3845b95a666">US 6.5</option>
                                    <option value="450b7ef575236df96a42816c448a03e0">US 7</option>
                                    <option value="c4d38ec34a0203c9799730fa75760162">US 7.5</option>
                                    <option value="3678a4bc494138c62c529f15b4103e45">US 8</option>
                                    <option value="655e5c520a63a7fd1592ea088b051e69">US 8.5</option>
                                    <option value="cb3f80e1babc079d802ca92d0760b2bd">US 9</option>
                                    <option value="ffc6670037f7ba5356247cea0537957d">US 9.5</option>
                                    <option value="7d6cde0d2cb6262febe73a0f5fef924a">US 10</option>
                                    <option value="6891a4d31dc5516e3b9fb7177bca001d">US 10.5</option>
                                    <option value="458aa765ade8646f71fb11721788454c">US 11</option>
                                    <option value="ced2d3d4b613b8a9f9bd8118bff92afe">US 11.5</option>
                            </select>
```

My code right now looks like this

```
size = soup.find('select', {'id': 'raff_size'})
```

Output:

```
<option value="">Storlek</option>
<option value="0bd9387c405ac2640932eadd797b1e04">US 6</option>
<option value="33edd81062f8c10efe67d0171150c35a">US 6.5</option>
<option value="6e4561c2ea5721da305d1f45c6d57bd4">US 7</option>
<option value="c286e5f2d8615f2915a286c005f62209">US 7.5</option>
<option value="dfeea836f795400a522d7a2f3ba8892f">US 8</option>
<option value="3b2d898de8ac62d22f40c4533cd45660">US 8.5</option>
<option value="df5f2bc78fc796b8063c1c01b061f177">US 9</option>
<option value="c00c36ac0986eebb6cf4379edc62bff7">US 9.5</option>
<option value="75621b2740d1fab3215c56615630d9ea">US 10</option>
<option value="5a0a97169ada6e204cbbf4477b3b1817">US 10.5</option>
<option value="a11401ac458c781223a96be8ed95ee28">US 11</option>
<option value="5549ce89be4e08c57592273856950f74">US 11.5</option>
<option value="3fdf35ec96de226bcb5f5c80ff99e28b">US 12</option>
</select>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Desired Output:

```
0bd9387c405ac2640932eadd797b1e04
33edd81062f8c10efe67d0171150c35a
6e4561c2ea5721da305d1f45c6d57bd4
c286e5f2d8615f2915a286c005f62209
dfeea836f795400a522d7a2f3ba8892f
3b2d898de8ac62d22f40c4533cd45660
df5f2bc78fc796b8063c1c01b061f177
c00c36ac0986eebb6cf4379edc62bff7
75621b2740d1fab3215c56615630d9ea
5a0a97169ada6e204cbbf4477b3b1817
a11401ac458c781223a96be8ed95ee28
5549ce89be4e08c57592273856950f74
3fdf35ec96de226bcb5f5c80ff99e28b
```

How would I get only the value? I tried

```
size = soup.find('select', {'id': 'raff_size'})
```

but it returned an error. If anyone can help that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not finding an easy way to get the value from the `option value` tag, that's why I decided to treat each line as a string and find the value between the quotation marks with `re.find_all()`:

```
import re
[re.findall(r'"(.*)"',str(x))[0] for x in BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser").find_all("select",{"id":'raff_size'})[0].find_all("option")]
```

This outputs:

```
['',
 'e8f7f9e31e2adb7ca18db3845b95a666',
 '450b7ef575236df96a42816c448a03e0',
 'c4d38ec34a0203c9799730fa75760162',
 '3678a4bc494138c62c529f15b4103e45',
 '655e5c520a63a7fd1592ea088b051e69',
 'cb3f80e1babc079d802ca92d0760b2bd',
 'ffc6670037f7ba5356247cea0537957d',
 '7d6cde0d2cb6262febe73a0f5fef924a',
 '6891a4d31dc5516e3b9fb7177bca001d',
 '458aa765ade8646f71fb11721788454c',
 'ced2d3d4b613b8a9f9bd8118bff92afe']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

sample_html = """
<select id="raff_size" name="size" class="required-entry">
                                    <option value="">Storlek</option>
                                                    <option value="e8f7f9e31e2adb7ca18db3845b95a666">US 6.5</option>
                                    <option value="450b7ef575236df96a42816c448a03e0">US 7</option>
                                    <option value="c4d38ec34a0203c9799730fa75760162">US 7.5</option>
                                    <option value="3678a4bc494138c62c529f15b4103e45">US 8</option>
                                    <option value="655e5c520a63a7fd1592ea088b051e69">US 8.5</option>
                                    <option value="cb3f80e1babc079d802ca92d0760b2bd">US 9</option>
                                    <option value="ffc6670037f7ba5356247cea0537957d">US 9.5</option>
                                    <option value="7d6cde0d2cb6262febe73a0f5fef924a">US 10</option>
                                    <option value="6891a4d31dc5516e3b9fb7177bca001d">US 10.5</option>
                                    <option value="458aa765ade8646f71fb11721788454c">US 11</option>
                                    <option value="ced2d3d4b613b8a9f9bd8118bff92afe">US 11.5</option>
                            </select>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "html.parser").find_all("option")
values = [o["value"] for o in soup if o["value"]]

for value in values:
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
e8f7f9e31e2adb7ca18db3845b95a666
450b7ef575236df96a42816c448a03e0
c4d38ec34a0203c9799730fa75760162
3678a4bc494138c62c529f15b4103e45
655e5c520a63a7fd1592ea088b051e69
cb3f80e1babc079d802ca92d0760b2bd
ffc6670037f7ba5356247cea0537957d
7d6cde0d2cb6262febe73a0f5fef924a
6891a4d31dc5516e3b9fb7177bca001d
458aa765ade8646f71fb11721788454c
ced2d3d4b613b8a9f9bd8118bff92afe
```

Comment: I totally missed just quoting the tag, good solution! +1

Comment: size = soup.find_all("option")
                values = [o["value"] for o in soup if o["value"]]
                for value in values:
                    print(value)
returns:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Are you getting this on the sample HTML or the real HTML?

Comment: I'm getting it on the real html

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to do this --
got this from `BeautifulSoup` documentation

after getting the `list` of all options -

```
size = soup.find('select', {'id': 'raff_size'})
```

size is a list and with each element of class tag

```
for item in size:
    print(item.attrs['value'])
```

this will give the desired output, which is:

```
['',
 'e8f7f9e31e2adb7ca18db3845b95a666',
 '450b7ef575236df96a42816c448a03e0',
 'c4d38ec34a0203c9799730fa75760162',
 '3678a4bc494138c62c529f15b4103e45',
 '655e5c520a63a7fd1592ea088b051e69',
 'cb3f80e1babc079d802ca92d0760b2bd',
 'ffc6670037f7ba5356247cea0537957d',
 '7d6cde0d2cb6262febe73a0f5fef924a',
 '6891a4d31dc5516e3b9fb7177bca001d',
 '458aa765ade8646f71fb11721788454c',
 'ced2d3d4b613b8a9f9bd8118bff92afe']
```

Comment: Please, check your answer twice - Why should iterating `soup.find('select', {'id': 'raff_size'})` aka `size` should print a single `list`?